# Graphics Primitive Selector

Tags: performance-tuning, front-end, gui-construction

### Goal and motivation

I want to build something that would intuitively work like:

```
Graphics @ PaneSelector[{True -> something, False -> {}}, Dynamic @ show]
```

as opposed to

```
Graphics @ Dynamic[If[show, something, {}]
```

The difference is that once `PaneSelector` is formatted then only information about `show` needs to travel between Kernel and FrontEnd.

With `Dynamic@If[...` whole `If[...]` needs to go back and forth. You can imagine that for large `something` that is a waste of time and may affect UX.

### Ideas and problems

My idea was to build something based on FrontEnd functions:

```
DynamicBox[FEPrivate`If[x, something, somethingElse]]
```

And **it works in some cases**:

```
With[{
  something     = First@ToBoxes@Graphics@Disk[],
  somethingElse = First@ToBoxes@Graphics@Circle[]
  },
 DynamicModule[{x = True},
  {
   Checkbox@Dynamic@x, 
   Graphics[RawBoxes@DynamicBox[FEPrivate`If[x, something, somethingElse]]]
  }
 ]
]
```

**It does not work when**:

- `x` is not a `DynamicModule` variable

  Sometimes you just can't use `DynamicModule` and want `x` to be a regular global symbol. Sometimes `DynamicModule` variables have troubles of updating dynamic so you want to avoid it even if you could use it. So you can see that is a quite limiting factor.
- `x` is a nested association.

  Assuming using `DynamicModule` you can use

  - `x = {True}`  `` FEPrivate`If[x[[1]],... `` or
  - `x = <|"a"->True|>`  `` FEPrivate`If[x["a"],... ``

  It will work fine but it can't handle:

  - `x = <|"a" -> <|"b" -> True|>|>` and `` FEPrivate`If[x["a", "b"],... ``

### Requirements

**My solution is limited** to `DynamicModule` variables which are arrays/lists or 'flat' associations.

**Desired solution** should work with arbitrary expression similarly to

```
PaneSelector[{...}, Dynamic @ expression]
```

If not it should at minimum support global symbols and nested associations.